# Azure SQL very slow INSERT in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, execution-plan, azure-sql-database

I have the following stored procedure, inserting new rows in a join table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewRows]
    @PropertyId int,
    @ItemGroupId int,
    @Discriminator nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO ItemProperty (PropertyId, Discriminator, ItemId)
    SELECT @PropertyId, @Discriminator, Id FROM Item WHERE ItemTypeId IN
        (SELECT Id From ItemType WHERE ItemGroupId = @ItemGroupId)
END;
```

In this case, items belong to a type which in turn belongs to a group. I want to create the rows for all items in a group.

I execute the stored procedure for test purposes using:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

EXEC InsertNewRows 1, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 2, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 3, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 4, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 5, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 6, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 7, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 8, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 9, 10, 'Discriminator';
EXEC InsertNewRows 10, 10, 'Discriminator';

COMMIT
```

The group used for testing contains around 80,000 items.

On my local SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition, the execution takes around 10 seconds to perform. When i try to run it on a S2 instance of Azure SQL it takes around 1 minute **per row** so in total over 10 minutes. I even tried scaling up to a P15 for testing, and it performs worse (twice the time) than my local SQL Server, running on a regular laptop. Disabling the indices for ItemId and PropertyId before executing roughly halves the speed both locally and in Azure, but the relative performance is the same.

I am aware of the fact that Azure SQL is generally quite slow on large INSERTs, but it seems like at least a P15 instance should outperform a local SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition. Is there anything i can do to tweak my stored procedure or database setup to make it work faster in Azure?

EDIT: Here is the execution plan for Azure:

[image: Execution plan Azure]

... and local:

[image: Execution plan Local]

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? statistics Io results? Any wait types for the sessions inserting?

Comment: Please post the table defs

Comment: Looks like the eager spool is causing the performance degradation. Those are performed inside tempdb, which is out of your control in Azure. Additionally, you might want to update statistics on ItemProperty at various stages during the batch, because that could also be causing problems.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: I would recommend to separate loading data to Azure and loading data to target table. Use Bulk operation to insert data to a staging table and then merge to target table.

Comment: @PawełTajs I'm interested in the total time for the operation in that case, and not only the insert to the DB (since this is an operation that has to be performed as a part of responding to a web request). Do you think that whole operation or just the table insert would take less time?

Comment: @TobiasBengtsson No, but this was edited over a year and a half ago and the only answer received no response. Generally a question open this long without an update does not get answered and ends up not being useful. If you're still interested in the answer, I'd recommend using http://pastetheplan.com to upload the query plans if you still have them instead of using pictures. That will increase your odds of getting responses. I can only retract my downvote if you edit again, but I will if I can.

Comment: Okay, I see the point. If i recall correctly the only answer did not work. We decided that this was probably an issue with Azure SQL itself and went on with redesigning the solution to not need the big insert. I don't have access to the source code anymore.

I think though that there is still a room for answers considering that Azure SQL is constantly evolving and a solution might appear as the service is updated. Also, the fact that the question is still open also provides useful information (namely that there seems to be no easy answer to the problem).

Answer (score 0):

This probably will not help but could you give it a try

```
INSERT INTO ItemProperty (PropertyId, Discriminator, ItemId)
SELECT @PropertyId, @Discriminator, Id 
  FROM Item 
  JOIN ItemType 
    ON ItemType.ID = Item.ItemTypeId  
   AND ItemType.ItemGroupId = @ItemGroupId
```